# NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE not working

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to use NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE (NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS to be precise) in a project but it seems it doesn't work.
I have tried:

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) @interface Dummy : NSObject
@end
```

Then when I have tried to check if the class is available:

```
if ([Dummy class]) {
  NSLog(@"Dummy available");
} else {
  NSLog(@"Dummy not available");
}
```

I always get "Dummy available", even in the iOS 6 simulator.
To check I have tried with NSURLSession:

```
if ([NSURLSession class]) {
  NSLog(@"NSURLSession available");
} else {
  NSLog(@"NSURLSession not available");
}
```

And, this time, I correctly get "NSURLSession not available".

Is there something I'm doing wrong?
Is there a compiler flag or something?

Comment: Because you can't weak link your own code? As far as I know `NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE` only works for shared frameworks. Basically the `NSURLSession` code works because there is no `NSURLSession` class in that OS version. What are you trying to do? If you want to use different classes depending on which features are available (e.g. to encapsulate NSURLSession and the old way in the same download helper class) have a look at class cluster. You have a public base class that returns a private class in alloc-init depending on the availability of `NSURLSession`. Your code only deals with the public class

Comment: Actually, this is for a framework (made using this template: https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework). I don't know if this is a shared framework (I'm pretty new to iOS development). I lowered the deployment target to 6.0 in order to avoid crash due to symbol not found with NSURLSession (which is available since iOS 7.0). Now there is no crash but the class using the NSURLSession is always available. I'd like to give a way for the developer to check if the class is available so they can make their own fallback.

Comment: (Using NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE in my framework doesn't work either)